# Need to ignore formatting characters

Tags: c#, filepath, string-literals

I'm displaying a folder path in a WPF TextBlock but formatting characters get applied resulting in:

```
c:    est
```

instead of

```
c:\test
```

Is there a way to disable all formatting on a control so I can display as intended?

```
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource StatusText}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is unrelated to WPF. You seem to use a string literal in your app like

```
string s = "C:\test";
```

This way, the tab is actually part of the string that you declare in your source file.

You need to either use a [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

```
string s = @"C:\test";
```

or use double backslashes to escape the backslash character.

```
string s = "C:\\test";
```

Comment: The problem is I'm setting the string by reading and deserializing from json: 

`using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Data/backups.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BackupSet>>(json);
            }`

Comment: @StratMan Then the JSON is already wrong. The JSON must contain double-backslashes. Otherwise inside the JSON, \t is already a tab and not backslash followed by t